# Links always open google first

Tags: gmail, google

This just seems wrong. When I click a link in an email (gmail), or anywhere else on Android, it *first* loads a google page then opens the link. Like google is tracking every link I click. Seems inappropriate. Any way to disable it?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "a google page"?

Comment: What's funny is you're using gmail. They literally need to work with the url of the link so they have access to that and more. If you're paranoid about them doing something then why use gmail?

Comment: That I use gmail was just an example. If I click a link in a pdf it does the same thing. Or if I am at some other website reading an article, same thing. every link opened by chrome seems to load a google page first, unless I hand type the url into chrome.

Comment: Also, if you read the question, it says, "...or anywhere else on Android..."

Answer (score 0):

As this behavior occurs with every app on your system most likely the configuration of the "Default Application" for `http` and `https` links has been changed.

You can configure all default Applications in the Android **Settings**. The exact path to the Default Applications settings depends on your Android version and device vendor (some vendors modify the Settings menu).

For example on Android 7 you have to open the **Apps** section and then the gear icon in the top right corner. Select the **Browser App** and you can choose which app to use as web browser.

On Android 8 there is in **Settings** the entry **Apps & Notifications** -> **Extended** -> **Default-Apps** where you can configure the default Browser app for example.

Comment: This is not the issue. If I click a link in gmail, and the link is specifically www.yahoo.com/somepage, then chrome opens and FIRST goes to a google page, loads it very briefly, then goes to the yahoo.com link. If I click a link in an article I am reading, same thing happens. FIRST it loads a google page, then it loads the link. I believe this is an inherent function of google tracking activity on android, but I could be wrong. a couple months ago, I think maybe their server had issues, because it would hang on the google page for awhile before finally loading the page I wanted.